# Timing event execution using jquery

Tags: jquery, events, time, execute

How can I time the execution of a JQuery function or event?  I don't mean executing an event or function after a timeout.  I want something like, capturing keyevents for (within) 20 seconds, not after 20 seconds. I have tried several ideas but not working the way I want.

Comment: What about using setTimeout to unbind from some event like keyup?

Comment: Can you give a use case

Comment: can you please provide a code example.  I have tried using setTimeout but but only allows keyevents after a time set.  But I want to be able to capture the keyevent within the time set not after.

Comment: A use case would be something like: when a button is clicked, start time, set time allowed to say 20 seconds.  Within the next 20 seconds, each time a user presses any key on the keyboard, increment counter.  After 20 seconds, display alert with counter value (which could be greater or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Given the markup

```
<p>Interval: <span id="interval"></span></p>
<p>Counter: <span id="counter"></span></p>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

You can do something like this to capture `keyup`s for 20 sec

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $("#start").click(function(){
        counter=0;
        var startTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

        $("body").on("keyup", function(){
            counter++;
            $("#counter").text(counter);
        });
        var intId = setInterval(function(){
            currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
            timeInterval = currentTime - startTime;
            $("#interval").text(timeInterval);
            if (timeInterval >= 20) {
                $("body").off("keyup");
                clearInterval(intId);
            }
        },1000);
    });
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpFBP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timer = 0;

    $(function()
    {

        if(timer > -1 && timer <= 20)
        {
            timer = setTimeout(function()
            {
                timer = timer + 1;
                alert(timer);
            }, 1);
        }

    });

</script>
```

and after if loop fail you can `unbind` events or whatever your requirement.